# Android Studio shortcut keys for windows, linux and mac

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

Android Studio shortcut key for Windows, Linux and Mac. For example in windows:

Run -> `Shift` + `F10`

Debug -> `Shift` + `F9`

Any others similar to this?

What are it's equivalent in Mac?

Comment: Can you not open File + Settings + Keymap and Search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Run -> Shift + F10` in Windows

if you want to change, you can do this..

`file` -> `settings` -> `keymap`

[image: Valid XHTML]

Change here.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).